# java - code for counting comparisons & execution time for algorithms not outputting correctly

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, bubble-sort, execution-time

In my java assignment, I have to count the number of comparisons that occur, and also the total execution time for selection sort, insertion sort, bubble sort, quick sort and merge sort algorithms. The following code below is a driver program to test the code that runs the algorithms while counting their execution times and comparisons. In the code, I initialized the list with values and ran it through them. The only output I get is "Sorted Lists..." which is just the first line. The rest of it isn't running and I'm lost. Please help.

```
public class SortingTest {

    //create 3 constant values
    static final int SIZE = 1000;//number of values in the lists
    static final int SORTED_ORDER = 0;//for sorted lists
    static final int RANDOM_ORDER = 1;//for unsorted lists

    //create the lists for each sorting algorithm
    static Integer[] selArr = new Integer[SIZE];
    static Integer[] insArr = new Integer[SIZE];
    static Integer[] bubArr = new Integer[SIZE];
    static Integer[] quiArr = new Integer[SIZE];
    static Integer[] merArr = new Integer[SIZE];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //perform the sorting on sorted lists
        performSorting(SORTED_ORDER);

        //perform the sorting on unsorted lists
        performSorting(RANDOM_ORDER);

        //perform the sorting on unsorted lists
        performSorting(RANDOM_ORDER);

    }

    private static void performSorting(int order) {
        if(order == SORTED_ORDER)//display if the lists are in sorted order or not
            System.out.println("Sorted Lists...");
        else 
            System.out.println("Unsorted Lists...");

            //initialize the lists in sorted order
            initLists(order);

            //initialize the number of comparisons and total execution time
            initComparisonsAndExecutionTime();

            //sort the lists
            sortLists();

            //display the number of comparisons and total execution time
            printComparisonsAndExecutionTime();
        }


    //initializes the lists with the same values
    private static void initLists(int order) {
        int number;
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
            if(order == SORTED_ORDER)
                number = new Integer(i);
            else
                number = new Integer((int)(Math.random()*SIZE));

            selArr[i] = number;
            insArr[i] = number;
            bubArr[i] = number;
            quiArr[i] = number;
            merArr[i] = number;
        }
    }

    /*initializes the number
    of comparisons and total execution time for each algorithm*/
    private static void initComparisonsAndExecutionTime() {
        Sorting.selectionSortComparisons = 0;
        Sorting.insertionSortComparisons = 0;
        Sorting.bubbleSortComparisons = 0;
        Sorting.quickSortComparisons = 0;
        Sorting.mergeSortComparisons = 0;
        Sorting.selectionSortExecutionTime = 0L;
        Sorting.insertionSortExecutionTime = 0L;
        Sorting.bubbleSortExecutionTime = 0L;
        Sorting.quickSortExecutionTime = 0L;
        Sorting.mergeSortExecutionTime = 0L;
    }

    /*calls each sorting algorithm with the 
    corresponding lists to sort the values*/
    private static void sortLists() {
        Sorting.selectionSort(selArr);
        Sorting.insertionSort(insArr);
        Sorting.bubbleSort(bubArr);
        Sorting.quickSort(quiArr);
        Sorting.mergeSort(merArr);
    }

    /*displays the number of comparisons and total execution time
    for each algorithm*/
    private static void printComparisonsAndExecutionTime() {
        System.out.println("----------------------");

        System.out.printf("%-15s%15s%15s\n", "SORTING METHOD",
                          "COMPARISONS", "EXEC.TIME(ns)");

        System.out.println("----------------------");

        System.out.printf("%-15s%15d%15d\n", "Selection sort",
                          Sorting.selectionSortComparisons,
                          Sorting.selectionSortExecutionTime);

        System.out.printf("%-15s%15d%15d\n", "Insertion sort",
                          Sorting.insertionSortComparisons,
                          Sorting.insertionSortExecutionTime);

        System.out.printf("%-15s%15d%15d\n", "Bubble sort",
                          Sorting.bubbleSortComparisons,
                          Sorting.bubbleSortExecutionTime);

        System.out.printf("%-15s%15d%15d\n", "Quick sort",
                          Sorting.quickSortComparisons,
                          Sorting.quickSortExecutionTime);

        System.out.printf("%-15s%15d%15d\n", "Merge sort",
                          Sorting.mergeSortComparisons,
                          Sorting.mergeSortExecutionTime);

        System.out.println("-----------------------\n\n");
    }
}
```

Here's the implementation for all the algorithms

```
    public class Sorting 
   {

public static int selectionSortComparisons = 0;
public static int insertionSortComparisons = 0;
public static int bubbleSortComparisons = 0;
public static int quickSortComparisons = 0;
public static int mergeSortComparisons = 0;
public static long selectionSortExecutionTime = 0L;
public static long insertionSortExecutionTime = 0L;
public static long bubbleSortExecutionTime = 0L;
public static long quickSortExecutionTime = 0L;
public static long mergeSortExecutionTime = 0L;

/**
 * Sorts the specified array of integers using the selection
 * sort algorithm.
 *
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 */

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    void selectionSort(T[] data)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();//stores the beginning time of 
selection sort algorithm
    int min;
    T temp;

    for (int index = 0; index < data.length-1; index++)
    {
        min = index;
        for (int scan = index+1; scan < data.length; scan++) {
            selectionSortComparisons++;//counts the number of 
comparisons in selection sort
            if (data[scan].compareTo(data[min])<0)
                min = scan;
              }


        swap(data, min, index);
        }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();//stores the ending time of 
selection sort
    selectionSortExecutionTime = endTime - startTime;//computes total 
execution time of selection sort
    }

/**
 * Swaps to elements in an array. Used by various sorting algorithms.
 * 
 * @param data   the array in which the elements are swapped
 * @param index1 the index of the first element to be swapped
 * @param index2 the index of the second element to be swapped
 */
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    void swap(T[] data, int index1, int index2)
{
    T temp = data[index1];
    data[index1] = data[index2];
    data[index2] = temp;
}

/**
 * Sorts the specified array of objects using an insertion
 * sort algorithm.
 *
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    void insertionSort(T[] data)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();//stores beginning time of 
insertion sort
    for (int index = 1; index < data.length; index++)
    {
        T key = data[index];
        int position = index;

        // shift larger values to the right 
        while (position > 0 && data[position-1].compareTo(key) > 0)
        {
            insertionSortComparisons++;//counts the number of 
comparisons in insertion sort
            data[position] = data[position-1];
            position--;
        }
        if (position > 0)
            insertionSortComparisons++;//counts the number of comparisons in insertion sort

        data[position] = key;
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();//stores ending time of insertion 
 sort
    selectionSortExecutionTime = endTime - startTime;//computes total execution time of selection sort
}

/**
 * Sorts the specified array of objects using a bubble sort
 * algorithm.
 *
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    void bubbleSort(T[] data)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();//stores the beginning of bubble sort
    int position, scan;
    T temp;

    for (position =  data.length - 1; position >= 0; position--)
    {
        for (scan = 0; scan <= position - 1; scan++)
        {
            bubbleSortComparisons++;//counts the number of comparisons in bubble sort
            if (data[scan].compareTo(data[scan+1]) > 0)
                swap(data, scan, scan + 1);
        }
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();//stores end of bubble sort
    selectionSortExecutionTime = endTime - startTime;//computes total execution time of bubble sort
}

/**
 * Sorts the specified array of objects using the merge sort
 * algorithm.
 *
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>>
    void mergeSort(T[] data)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();//stores beginning of merge sort
    mergeSort(data, 0, data.length - 1);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();//stores end of merge sort
    selectionSortExecutionTime = endTime - startTime;//computes total execution time of merge sort
}

/**
 * Recursively sorts a range of objects in the specified array using the
 * merge sort algorithm.
 *
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 * @param min  the index of the first element 
 * @param max  the index of the last element
 */
private static <T extends Comparable<T>>
    void mergeSort(T[] data, int min, int max)
{
    if (min < max)
    {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        mergeSort(data, min, mid);
        mergeSort(data, mid+1, max);
        merge(data, min, mid, max);
    }
}

/**
 * Merges two sorted subarrays of the specified array.
 *
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 * @param first the beginning index of the first subarray 
 * @param mid the ending index fo the first subarray
 * @param last the ending index of the second subarray
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Comparable<T>>
    void merge(T[] data, int first, int mid, int last)
{
    T[] temp = (T[])(new Comparable[data.length]);

    int first1 = first, last1 = mid;  // endpoints of first subarray
    int first2 = mid+1, last2 = last;  // endpoints of second subarray
    int index = first1;  // next index open in temp array

    //  Copy smaller item from each subarray into temp until one
    //  of the subarrays is exhausted
    while (first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2)
    {
        mergeSortComparisons++;//count the number of comparisons in merge sort
        if (data[first1].compareTo(data[first2]) < 0)
        {
            temp[index] = data[first1];
            first1++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[index] = data[first2];
            first2++;
        }
        index++;
    }

    //  Copy remaining elements from first subarray, if any
    while (first1 <= last1)
    {
        temp[index] = data[first1];
        first1++;
        index++;
    }

    //  Copy remaining elements from second subarray, if any
    while (first2 <= last2)
    {
        temp[index] = data[first2];
        first2++;
        index++;
    }

    //  Copy merged data into original array
    for (index = first; index <= last; index++)
        data[index] = temp[index];
```

}

```
/**
 * Sorts the specified array of objects using the quick sort algorithm.
 * 
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    void quickSort(T[] data)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();//stores beginning of quick sort
    quickSort(data, 0, data.length - 1);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();//stores end of quick sort
    selectionSortExecutionTime = endTime - startTime;//computes total execution time of quick sort
    }

/**
 * Recursively sorts a range of objects in the specified array using the
 * quick sort algorithm. 
 * 
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 * @param min  the minimum index in the range to be sorted
 * @param max  the maximum index in the range to be sorted
 */
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    void quickSort(T[] data, int min, int max)
{
    if (min < max)
    {
        // create partitions
        int indexofpartition = partition(data, min, max);

        // sort the left partition (lower values)
        quickSort(data, min, indexofpartition - 1);

        // sort the right partition (higher values)
        quickSort(data, indexofpartition + 1, max);
    }
}

/**
 * Used by the quick sort algorithm to find the partition.
 * 
 * @param data the array to be sorted
 * @param min  the minimum index in the range to be sorted
 * @param max  the maximum index in the range to be sorted
 */
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    int partition(T[] data, int min, int max)
{
    T partitionelement;
    int left, right;
    int middle = (min + max) / 2;

    // use the middle data value as the partition element
    partitionelement = data[middle];
    // move it out of the way for now
    swap(data, middle, min);

    left = min;
    right = max;

    while (left < right)
    {
        // search for an element that is > the partition element
        while (left < right && data[left].compareTo(partitionelement) <= 0)
            quickSortComparisons++;//counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
            left++;

        // search for an element that is < the partition element
        while (data[right].compareTo(partitionelement) > 0)
            quickSortComparisons++;//counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
            right--;

        quickSortComparisons++;//counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
        // swap the elements
        if (left < right)
            quickSortComparisons++;//counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
            swap(data, left, right);
    }

    // move the partition element into place
    swap(data, min, right);

    return right;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting the edit Gurtug. If you could help with the problem that would be great :)

Comment: We can't help as half of the important code is missing. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: I thought it would be too long to post the code where all the algorithms were implemented. I can still put it in if I should

Comment: And by the way: I hope you understand that your code is almost fully "procedural". That isn't "wrong" perse, but the idea of Java is to use an object oriented programming style normally.

Comment: You don't have to post ALL code. You might build a reduced example that we can fully run to see the problem. I understand that your sorting class must be too huge, simply because it isn't following OOP ideas...

Comment: @GhostCat I understand that.  I bet my code could be WAY more concise and neat and follow OOP principles but I'm just looking to make it work somehow. I'm just trying  to finish meet my deadline for this assignment lol i'm so stressed gotta get it done.

Comment: Sure. My suggestion: take your current code, make a full copy of it, and in that copy remove ALL but one of the sorting styles. Then post that following the [mcve] rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding some prints to help debug your code. I found out that your quick sort method runs into an infinite loop.

The output was:

```
Sorted Lists...
Lists Initialized!
Comparisons and Exec time initialized!
Selection done!
Insertion done!
Bubble done!
```

When I commented this line  `Sorting.quickSort(quiArr);`, I got the following output:

```
----------------------
SORTING METHOD     COMPARISONS  EXEC.TIME(ns)
----------------------
Selection sort          499500        2726141
Insertion sort          243586              0
Bubble sort             499500              0
Quick sort                   0              0
Merge sort                8697              0
-----------------------
```

Which made me check your code to set the execution time for each sorting method. Looks like all methods set `Sorting.selectionSortExecutionTime`, as you can see on the following snippet from mergeSort:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] data) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();// stores
                            // beginning
                            // of
                            // merge
                            // sort
        mergeSort(data, 0, data.length - 1);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();// stores
                            // end
                            // of
                            // merge
                            // sort
        /* Wrong variable */
        selectionSortExecutionTime = endTime - startTime;// computes
                                // total
                                // execution
                                // time
                                // of
                                // merge
                                // sort
}
```

I did some debugging in the quick sort method and found the following:
The while loops inside the `while(left<right)` didn't have curly braces, so the `left++` and `right--` where left out, only the `quickSortComparisons++` was inside them. Here's the fixed code with comments pointing out what I described:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] data,
        int min,
        int max) {
    T partitionelement;
    int left, right;
    int middle = (min + max) / 2;
    // use the middle data value as the
    // partition element
    partitionelement = data[middle];
    // move it out of the way for now
    swap(data, middle, min);
    left = min;
    right = max;
    while (left < right) {
        // search for an element that is >
        // the partition element
        while (left < right
                && data[left].compareTo(partitionelement) <= 0){
            // counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
            quickSortComparisons++;
            left++; // <--- this was not in the while loop
        }
        quickSortComparisons++; // <--- I believe you should have this one too
        // search for an element that is <
        // the partition element
        while (data[right].compareTo(partitionelement) > 0){
            // counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
            quickSortComparisons++;
            right--; // <--- this wasn't in the while loop neither
        }
        // counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
        quickSortComparisons++;
        // swap the elements
        if (left < right)
            quickSortComparisons++;// counts the number of comparisons in quick sort
        swap(data, left, right);
    }
    // move the partition element into place
    swap(data, min, right);
    return right;
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: I fixed the execution time variable for all of them. And when I commented quick sort out, they all seem to work! This is awesome thanks for getting me this far! But I'm still stuck on quick sort. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I'll do a quick search and try to find a fix. As soon as I can, I'll let you now!

Comment: I found the problem and edited the answer. I'm not sure if that is expected but the mergeSortComparisons is extremely low compared to others, maybe you are missing some.(Sorry if that is how it should be, I don't really know how merge sort works)

Comment: I luckily managed to figure it out last night before I saw your answer today. As far as I know, yes merge sort is supposed to be that low. Still thank you so much for all your help. You are a lifesaver :)